# Listar dados em um ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

Estou com um uma dúvida na hora de listar dados específicos de uma tabela num `ListView`. Quando eu utilizo um método para listar, consigo pegar todos os registros da tabela, só que eu gostaria de filtrar esses dados pelo `id` e jogar no `ListView`.

Com o método abaixo consigo listar todos os pedidos da tabela, como faço para listar os pedidos de um `id` especifico, passando por parâmetro o `id`.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPedidos);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(StatusActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Carregando...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        Call<List<Pedidos>> call = ApiClient.getUsuario().getPedidos();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Pedidos>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Pedidos>> call, Response<List<Pedidos>> response) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();

                final List<Pedidos> listaPedidos = response.body();
                if (listaPedidos!=null){
                    PedidosAdapter adapter = new PedidosAdapter(getBaseContext(), listaPedidos);
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Log.d("my_tag", "Entrou no Onresponse: " + response.body());
                } else {
                    Log.d("my_tag", "Entrou no else: " + response.body());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Pedidos>> call, Throwable t) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Problema de acesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Deve implementar no serviço um método que faça isso para depois acede-lo assim: `ApiClient.getUsuarioById(id).getPedidos();`

Comment: Por que você simplesmente não passa a lista já filtrada pro adapter? Ou você precisaria da lista completa e o filtro por id seria aplicado dinamicamente?

Comment: Isso parece retrofit. Você tem que fazer desta forma: `ApiClient.getUsuario().getPedidos(id)`, Porem tem que entrar dentro do método `getPetidos` de altera-lo para receber um id. Tente editar a pergunta e colocar o que tem dentro do método `getPedidos()`

Comment: @AckLay, eu já criei o método que lista todos os pedidos de um determinado cliente, mas ainda não consegui chama-lo dentro do onResponde: 
 @GET("Pedidos/buscarId/{id}") Call<Pedidos> getPedidosPorId(@Path("id") int id); 
Agora eu preciso chamar esse método e não estou conseguindo.
O método getPedidos( ) lista todos os registros da tabela, mas eu não preciso dele, preciso de um que liste todos os pedidos de um determinado cliente, ou seja do cliente que vai estar logado no momento.